Captive Portal Behavior of Safari on iOS
For a Raspberry Pi without Internet connection that provides a WiFi access point so that it can be controlled through a Web interface, I set up Bind9 to connect all domains to the one IP address of the Raspberry Pi. This IP address is 10.123.234.1 in my proof of concept.
The following configuration is placed on the Raspberry Pi (.com.net was chosen on purpose because at least firefox treats commonly known top-level domains in a different manner than unknown ones).
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA test.com.net. root.com.net. (
                  1     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
    IN  NS  10.123.234.1
*   IN  A   10.123.234.1

It partly works as expected when I try to connect from Firefox (Ubuntu). For instance, if I enter "a.org" on Firefox, the Web server behind 10.123.234.1:80 responds and Firefox is okay with that.
However, on Safari (iOS) that does not work. Only entering "test.com.net" redirects to 10.123.234.1:80. But everything else leads to Safari give up.
Both behaviors are not really desired. For instance, from iOS I expected doing captive portal detection and automatically show the page of 10.123.234.1:80.
What is the missing link to make that work?

I'm assuming that you made a.org work by distributing "test.com.net" as your domain search suffix via DHCP (as that's the only plausible explanation; a DNS server by itself cannot attract requests otherwise). The problem with that is that there is no one agreed way to implement a search suffix – different systems disagree on whether it should be applied to names that already have multiple components (and which a person would already consider "qualified" even though DNS doesn't).
So when you enter a.org:

some systems will apply the domain search suffix (as technically it's not a fully qualified domain; only a.org. would be),
but other systems will not (as it already has multiple components and most users consider it already fully qualified),

and unfortunately there is no way to reconcile the two, other than not doing that in the first place.

More than that, such an approach only works with requests that honor the search suffix at all, and many won't.
The more correct way to make it work would be to have the DNS server reply with this address unconditionally, without expecting any particular domain suffix. With BIND, I'm not sure of the best way of implementing that – I would first try defining zone "." with the wildcard, but it might be that you need to use the RPZ feature (Response Policy Zone), which is BIND's mechanism for doing such arbitrary overwriting.
But when we implemented a captive portal at work, we deliberately did not perform any DNS rewriting whatsoever – for one, because some clients cached the fake response even after the user had logged in; and we found it unnecessary in general. It was much more reliable to redirect packets at IP level (using the firewall's DNAT rules), which was something that you kind of have to do anyway in order to prevent trivial bypass of the portal.

Thank you for the detailed response. You are right, I instructed dnsmasq behind NetworkManager to send the search domains com.net and net. If the solution is possible without iptables, I would really appreciate that. Please consider that it is not the intention to prevent intentional bypasses (there is no network behind the device, the only device the connected client can physically talk to is the device anyway) but only to help the user see something. Actually the problem is that entering a domain, from the user interaction process point of view, gives no benefit but is unwanted hassle.

I tried your suggestion to define zone "." and it partly works successful! Works: redirect to always the same IP address on iOS and Android. Does not work: immediately open captive portal (it only appeared once on my PC). However, the latter is a nice to have and I will further play with your suggestions to see if I could make it work! Many thanks so far for the very helpful ideas.

At the heart of captive portal operation is something that does the necessary AITM attacks on all insecure HTTP requests from  clients that haven't successfully dealt with the portal web page yet. You didn't mention setting up such a tool, such as nodogsplash (NDS), so that's probably the part you are missing. There are lots of tutorials on how to set up captive portal on Raspberry Pi, and they all include setting up NDS or alternatives. I'd recommend following a tutorial your first time as there are a lot of moving parts.

I am aware of those tools but even if I used such a tool, finally I would need to understand what they do internally. Understanding what should happen is the intention of my question. Apart from that, the desired captive portal is not about logging in but help the user open the Web interface of the device. So there is a different intention than NDS was developed for.
